# remove does not deleting child record ,Same record can be deleted through JPQL

Tags: oracle10g, jpa-2.0

I want to delete a record from DB ,where i have PK . If i call JPQL named query as below its deleting

```
<named-query name="delete">
    <query>

        DELETE
        FROM
            IPRInterestRate interestRate
        WHERE
            interestRate.interestRateId = :interestRateId

    </query>
</named-query>
```

But i require to do some logic in @PostRemove so tried using find and remove as below

```
public void interestRateDeleteById(Long interestRateId) {

    entityManager.remove(entityManager.find(IPRInterestRate.class, interestRateId));
    entityManager.flush();
}
```

but transaction is success but record is not removed .

Comment: Did you commit the session which deletes?

Comment: Yes its committed through Spring Transaction , And deleting entity has many to one relationship with other entity .

Comment: As far as I know there's an optional command when you create the foreign key to specify what happens when the parent key is deleted.
This might help 
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php